# is there a function in R for dataframe object that has same operation with countifs() formula in excel?

Tags: r, excel

i have a data.frame with 10000 obs and 14 variables in R.
i wanna to write a command same as count ifs formula in excel.

Comment: would this work for you? `sum(ifelse(test = ..., yes = 1, no = 0))`

Comment: my dataframe name is "df"

Comment: could you write a commend by this name? i mean "df"

Comment: suppose that my dataframe has som character variable.

Comment: Hi @aboozarvarzi. Please review how [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [how to make a good reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your question is about to get closed for not meeting SO's posting standards. In short: Provide reproducible & minimal sample data, a clear & complete problem statement (main post, not in comments), and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to provide some example data in your question. Here are a couple examples based on the built-in `iris` data:

```
df <- iris

# count how many records have species virginica
sum(ifelse(df$Species == "virginica", 1, 0))
# [1] 50

# count how many records have Petal.Length < 1.5
sum(ifelse(df$Petal.Length < 1.5, 1, 0))
# [1] 24

# count how many records have species setosa and Petal.Length > 1.5
sum(ifelse(df$Species == "setosa" & df$Petal.Length > 1.5, 1, 0))
# [1] 13

# count how many records have species setosa or virginica
sum(ifelse(df$Species == "setosa" | df$Species == "virginica", 1, 0))
# [1] 100

# same as above, different syntax
sum(ifelse(df$Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica"), 1, 0))
# [1] 100
```

Comment: None of these `ifelse` statements are necessary, as the conditional statements already return TRUE & FALSE. For example, the first example should be `sum(iris$Species == "virginica")`. That side, I'd be better to have OP improve his post first and clarify on what it is he/she is after. Stack Overflow helps with *specific* coding questions. General tutorial-like help is not a good fit for SO. This is not to discredit your contribution but to encourage OP to spend time familiarising him/herself with basic R syntax.

Comment: Great point, removing `ifelse` is simpler and faster, thank you! Also good point - I shouldn't have to guess what OP wants. Thanks!

Comment: i give my response. thank you so much!!!!